# Database Table Inheritance

Tags: sql, database-design, inheritance

Is it possible for a table to inherit on-to-many sub tables? (I think thats how its meant to be worded :P) In others words:

```
 PersonBase can be PersonA and/or PersonD and/or PersonC
```

However in this particular case it needs to be possible for **PersonBase** to exist multiple times as **PersonD** (there are reasons for it), could I do it this way? Or should I create another table say **TableD** such that **PersonBase** is a **PersonD** which has a one to many relationship with **TableD**. However I would prefer to be able to do it so that **PersonBase** can be multiple **PersonDs** if possible.

Thanks All

P.S. I apologize if my question seems naive.

Comment: SQL has no such concept itself. However, many ORMS add such mappings, as do OORDMBS. Looking at how, say, this is handled in both PostgreSQL and Hibernate may be beneficial.

Comment: @Matthew Cox, Sorry I don't think so, multiple inheritance allows one to inherit from multiple tables, yes? What I need is for PersonBase to exists multiple times in PersonD, in other words say we have John Dow, what I would need is for John Dow to be able to exists more than once in PersonD, that if I search for John Dow(ID 5) it might possibly return two entries from PersonD. Sorry I should probably rephrase the question a bit :)

Comment: This seems to me like duplicating rows? If they were all in one table John D. would exists in two rows?

Answer (score 4):

postgresql has actual table inheritance just like OOP. A Base table columns are inherited by "sub-tables" it also supports even multiple base classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you describe in the first case, between `PersonBase` (supertype) and `PersonA`,  `PersonC` (subtype), are `1:1` relationships (supertype/subtype), while in the second case, between  `PersonBase` and `PersonD`, is a `1:n` relationship.